# how to write data in a file with android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to write a code for an application that displays the values of the magnetometer sensor and save these data in a file. 
I wrote the following code but the problem is in my file I find only one line containing the last values.

```
FloatingActionButton fab;
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(  new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
       final Thread t = new Thread() {
           File openfilename=  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myfile.txt");
           FileOutputStream f;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                TextView tv;
                                tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

                                tv.setText(" x="+Float.toString(xx)+"    y="+Float.toString(yy)+"    z="+Float.toString((zz))+"      Puissance="+Float.toString(magneticStrenght));

                                try {
                                     FileOutputStream f =new FileOutputStream(openfilename);

                                    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(f);
                                    pw.append("\n x="+Float.toString(xx)+"    y="+Float.toString(yy)+"    z="+Float.toString((zz))+"      Puissance="+Float.toString(magneticStrenght));
                                    //close the file
                                    pw.flush();
                                    pw.close();
                                    f.close();

                                } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                                    //do something if an IOException occurs.
                                    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        t.start();
```

Can you please try to help and see what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the `FileOutputStream` in append mode, by passing a boolean `true` as the second parameter

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(openfilename, true);
```

See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) for more details

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) you should use this constructor to open the file in **append** mode :

```
FileOutputStream fStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
```

As you've not used the append flag while creating the FileOutputStream object, you're overwriting the previous data in the file everytime you're opening and writing it.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the other answers but the problem with the code stems from certain logic errors and omissions.

It seems you have some things conceptually wrong. At what point are you trying to write the text out to file? You seem to be creating a loop and within that loop, you create a text file on each iteration where data is written to the file.

This will always result in the problem you've described.

Step back, think about the logic here and then place the file writing code into a separate function. Call that function only when you want the data to be saved (for example; when leaving the textview, tapping a button on the activity, or some other useful time).

Calling the write procedure should happen only once you have finished collecting your data but before the activity is off screen. As written your logic may even be creating multiple files and always writes only one line of code to that file.  Given your specific task, you might want to try using a StringBuffer and output it's content to file. Searching SO and Google will give you tons of examples.

It's unclear why you are showing the data in a textview so you may want to capture that data independently of a textview and show what is needed only when necessary.

Comment: In fact I want to save the values of the magnetomere every 500ms that is why I have the loop